# Argument to give to .setNumberFormat() in order to display Timezone

Tags: datetime, formatting, google-apps-script

I have a google apps script where I copy the date of the day in a cell. I would like to set the format of the cell to see something like "22 Aug 2012 - 23:55 - PDT".

I don't find a clear list of all the arguments I can give to the method .setNumberFormat(). I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx but it doesn't seem to work with all arguments.

From trial and error I managed to guess "d MMM yy - HH:mm" which best fit my purpose, but I would like to add the timezone at the end ( "d MMM yy - HH:mm - Timezone"). Any clue ?

Thanks,

edelans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is set the format of the cells in the spreadsheet to plain text explicitly. Otherwise, it will be formatted as a date and displayed in whatever default format it chooses to based on regional settings.

Next, use the Utilities.formatDate() function to format your date. For your requirement, use the format string as

`// This will return a string.`

`var str = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PDT", "dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm - z");`

Comment: Ok Srik, thanks for the workaround, but isn't it possible to use .setNumberFormat() ?

Comment: I guess you can. Maybe you can add z at the end of your format string. The documentation for this method doesn't say anything useful at all